# How to blur and certain zone of an ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, blur

I'm currently working on an application and I was wondering if they were any way of blurring only a certain part of an imageView, let me show you with some picture :

**Here's what I have.**

[image: Here's the Original One]

**Here's what I want (First part of the view):**

[image]

To make it easy to understand, I want to blur I'd like to be able to blur only the top side or bottom side of the diagonal of a rectangle image.

I've done some research and found some help on how to blur the background of a textView but not What i'd like to do

Thanks

Comment: [Here's](http://developers.500px.com/2015/03/17/a-blurring-view-for-android.html) a blog post explaining how to implement a bluring `View`. You should be able to easily implement it so it only blurs a triangle.